# How do you provision new node on the cloud with puppet 2?

Tags: amazon-ec2, cloud, puppet

Every node should have the valid certificate to connect to the puppet-master.

In the past, the nodes are static and setup by the operator and execute the ca-sign by themselves.
Today, the nodes are created dynamically by the api of cloud providers, such as AWS, Azure, etc.
To provision a new node is a problem because we don't know the node's domain or IP, before it is running and attached to an IP.

I found some strategies on the Internet:

1. Make a pre-sign ca and ship it with node created
2. Just enable the autosign feature anyway
3. Leverage the external node classifier

About the pre-sign method, it will be like this:
https://gist.github.com/zipkid/3496753

The related work is

1. Generate the ca for your node
2. Put the ca files to the new node

Perhaps you want to change the hostname for the external node classifier.
It is better for the prebuilt image like the ec2 image, 
we can build it with the presign ca.

About the enable autosign method, just edit the autosign rules. 
I think it is good for a special case like the ec2's vpc, because every node cannot be connected from the Internet.

About the external node classifier method, there are many variations:

1. Validate the node, if it is a valid node to include the useful classes, or the noop class
2. Validate the node, if it is a valid node to add the new entry to autosign rule

How do you provision a cloud node with Puppet's ca ? Could you like to share it ?

PS. puppet 3's new feature [*policy-based-autosigning*](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/ssl_autosign.html#policy-based-autosigning)